# Using nginx as Forward proxy in kubernetes

Tags: nginx, proxy, kubernetes

I am really new to kubernetes and nginx. I am able to use it as a reverse-proxy by setting up ingress resource, however, I am not sure about how should I use it to forward the request from kubernetes to a particular host.

My case is as follows:
I have a container running in kubernetes pod which access an external api url (example www.xxx.com) with some parameters, however, because I have blocked the outgoing requests for all the pods, it can not access that api url.

To solve this I want to setup nginx proxy which will forward my request to the actual api url.

Being new to this and having lack of proper steps documented anywhere to achieve this, I am really stuck. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

What you could do is to define a Service object that points to your external API endpoint. This is done by creating an Endpoint object and a Service object both with the same name.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors

Once you have your service, you could create an Ingress rule that would forward the traffic to that service. Make sure that the Ingress controller can access your API endpoint.