# In-cluster nginx proxy (sidecar) in Kubernetes to re-write headers

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, http-headers, http-proxy, nginx-ingress

## Background

I have an in-cluster Kubernetes pod/application that works fine when accessing it via an `nginx-ingress` ingress controller (requires specific `Host` HTTP header), but it cannot be accessed by other in-cluster pods/applications (i.e. for testing) due to the pods using different host names (e.g. `service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local`) rather than the FQDN of the K8S master (in the LAN).

---

## Plan So Far

I think the only way to (easily) resolve this is to setup an in-cluster forward-proxy `nginx` instance. Ideally, the service is either a side-car for the pod that needs to have headers re-written, or it needs to be a general in-cluster proxy that multiple services can access.

---

Question

- How would I setup an in-cluster `nginx` forward proxy service?
- Should it be a sidecar, or a general service any pod can access?

---

## Work So Far

[The linked "similar" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921522/using-nginx-as-forward-proxy-in-kubernetes) don't appear to be helpful for my use case (i.e. don't show how to configure an in-cluster proxy), or are focused on proxying to IPs external to the cluster (i.e. I need to proxy HTTP requests, and re-write their headers, to in-cluster resources).

Comment: So, your ingress rules require a specific DNS name for the host? i.e. the pods themselves cannot use the FQDN to access the master through the ingress controller?

Comment: @Cloud Correct: and all I/O **must** remain within the cluster (i.e. I can't just redirect to the ingress controller via an external route: all I/O must be within the cluster and not go to the outside world).

Comment: Can't you remove this limitation from your app side? Ingress is for external access, if you need in-cluster communication you need to use services or make your pods access the internet to reach your ingress externally (that does't make sense too).

Comment: You could potentially use a CoreDNS `rewrite` rule (i.e. effectively create a DNS alias for in-cluster services which is really just an alias for the ingress controller service, `svc/nginx-ingress-controller`), and add the alias to the ingress controller policy/rules for `nginx-ingress` (i.e. `ing/ing-rule-name`). Would likely be easier that adding an additional service/side-car/forward-proxy within the cluster. Kind of ugly, but works (if you just need to re-write the `Host`/target; if you need to do additional header mangling, you'll need an additional `nginx` forward proxy).

Comment: @KoopaKiller Sadly no: I have zero control over the applications, nor access to their source.

Comment: Could you post an example of the desired behavior? How your frontend need to receive the request? Are you using some cloud provider, or bare metal installation ? If you are using cloud provider, maybe an internal load balancer help you.

Comment: Figured it out, but solution is proprietary. Voting to close.